# Existe uma palavra portuguesa para "transmogrify"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução, tradução-inglês

Numa [tira de Calvin and Hobbes](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2017/03/28) vi ser usada a palavra "transmogrified".

O dicionário Merriam-Webster [diz sobre "transmogrify"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transmogrify) que é uma palavra humorosa, de origem no século XVII, que significa:

> To change or alter greatly and often with grotesque or humorous effect.
>
> ---
>
> Alterar ou transformar absolutamente, e normalmente com um sentido humorístico ou grotesco.

- Temos alguma boa palavra ou expressão para "transmogrificar", em Português?

Comment: Eh pá, eu pensei que isto fosse uma invenção recente, o que nos daria mais licença para inventar também. Mas diz o [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transmogrify) que já vem de 1656!

Comment: A palavra é nova também para mim. A tradução mais literal seria "metamorfosear". Ou simplesmente "transformar", mas acho que perde a magia.

Comment: Eu conhecia, mas como a forma é latinada, nunca imaginei que não houvesse o _transmogrificar_ no português...

Comment: Transmodificar em aportuguesamento de internet

Answer (score 4):

A tirinha do Calvin foi traduzida no Brasil como 'Transmogrifador' e me parece que foi a melhor tradução.  Assim como a palavra original inglesa não tem significado, a tradução não precisa possuir um. É simplesmente uma invenção de uma criança,  não é algo que existe.

Comment: Onde viste a tirinha no Brasil? Se for online, tens como postar um link para ela?

Comment: Eu tenho essa tirinha em um livro, e acho que também tenho recortada do Jornal O Globo. A que foi recortada eu muito provavelmente não tenho como indicar a data, mas certamente foi alguma coisa entre 1987 e 1989. Vou procurar, mas peço não se incomode com a demora.

Comment: "a palavra original inglesa não tem significado" = Já olhou num dicionário?

Comment: Hum... quase seis anos depois, realmente não me lembro se olhei em um dicionário. Se  é que procurei, não encontrei - caso contrário não teria dito aquilo. O que você sabe a respeito? Tem uma informação concreta e mais útil do que uma pergunta inconclusiva? Conhece algum dicionário que contenha definição para essa palavra?

Answer (score 3):

Procurei algumas traduções para transmogrify. Acredito que literalmente a tradução é *transformar*. Pesquisando, achei alguns exemplos no http://www.linguee.com. E acredito que uma ótima tradução para isso seria *transfigurar*.

http://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/translation/transmogrify.html

Comment: Mas então que dizer das traduções de "to transform" e de "to transfigure"? Traduções são um assunto mesmo difícil. :(

Comment: Uma alternativa era tentar achar a mesma tirinha em português e daí podíamos comparar.

Answer (score 1):

"Transmogrify" é uma palavra bem pouco usada em inglês, apesar de [fontes na internet](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transmogrify) situarem uma origem antiga. Não sei se era realmente conhecida  antes da tirinha do Calvin & Hobbes do transmogrifier.

Eu usaria "transmogrificar" (o verbo fica estranho, mas o nome do aparalho "transmogrificador" é facilmente identificado como "um aparelho que causa transformações". Por outro lado só "transformador" ou "modificador" para traduzir essa tirinha não teria o impacto desejado pelo autor (isso é: você estraga o quadrinho se usar uma palavra normal aí.)

Answer (score 0):

Transfigurar seria a palavra mais próxima. É quando algo muda de aparência sem mudar a essência daquilo que é. Digo próxima pois o termo inglês implica um valoração pejorativa, enquanto no português não há tal conotação.